# gamma functions as infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, gamma-function, beta-function

The question is to prove the given expression

$$\frac{1}{n+1}+m\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{m(m+1)}{2!}\frac{1}{n+3}+\frac{m(m+1)(m+2)}{3!}\frac{1}{n+4}+...=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(1-m)}{\Gamma(n-m+2)}$$

where $n>-1$ and $m<1$. I have tried it by substituting $n!$(i.e., $2!$, $3!$, and so on...) by $n\Gamma(n)$ but that didn't really help me.

I have been trying to solve the series but couldn't proceed a single step in this. Can someone please give me some clue on how to proceed?

Comment: Why is this tagged "mathematical physics"? This has nothing to do with physics. **EDIT:** I have removed the tag.

Comment: You can perhaps use the fact that 
$$\prod_{i=0}^k (m+i)=\frac{\Gamma(m+k+1)}{\Gamma(m)}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{{1 \over n + 1} +
m{1 \over n + 2} + {m\pars{m + 1} \over 2!}
{1 \over n + 3} }
\\[2mm] + &\
\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\left.\vphantom{\huge A^{A^{A}}}%
{m\pars{m + 1}\pars{m + 2}
\over 3!}{1 \over n + 4} + \ldots
\,\right\vert_{\substack{%
n\ >\ -1
\\
m\ <\ 1}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
{\pars{m + k - 1}!/\pars{m - 1}! \over
\pars{n + k + 1}k!} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
{{m + k - 1 \choose k} \over n + k + 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
{{-m \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k} \over n + k + 1} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
{-m \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}\int_{0}^{1}t^{n + k}\,\dd t \\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}t^{n}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
{-m \choose k}\pars{-t}^{k}\,\dd t =
\int_{0}^{1}t^{n}\pars{1 - t}^{-m}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{\Gamma\pars{n + 1}\Gamma\pars{-m + 1} \over
\Gamma\pars{n - m + 2}} \\ &
\end{align}

Comment: I didn't get a part here...what is $\begin{pmatrix}m+k-1\\k\end{pmatrix}$ inside the summation in the third line? what does that mean? and where did the $k!$ vanish?...please explain a bit after that step..

Comment: @CuriousMind It's a definition: $\displaystyle{p \choose q} =
{p! \over q!\left(p - q\right)!}$ is a $\color{red}{\tt binomial}$. See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

Comment: Thank you very much @Felix Marin